# Troubles with predict() function (probably easy to solve)

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, predict

all.

This is the first question I make in this forum. I'am a beginner, as you all will immediately tell.

I´m doing a small task in which I must compare a training model with a test model. The point is that the training model has much more rows than the test one.

Through a linear regression model, I wish to compare both models, but when I use the predict() function I get the following error:

"newdata" had 3456 rows but variables found fave 7689 rows.

This is what I did:

```
regression = lm(train$students~train$subjects, train)
```

(train is the trining database)

```
prediction = predict(regression, test)
```

(test is the testing database)

I don´t know if I´m using the predict() function correctly. Could someone tell me what I did wrong?

Thank you so much in advance your your help and kindness!

Comment: Try adding `type='response'` as an argument to the predict function. I can't help much more without a reproducible example.

Comment: Instead try   
`regression = lm(students ~ subjects, train)   
prediction = predict(regression, test)`

Comment: Thanks a lot, G5W!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't refer to variables as `data$var` in a formula. Never. Ever.

What is happening is that you fitted a model with variables named `train$students` and `train$subjects`. To predict from the model R will look for a variable named `train$subjects` in the test set, `test`. Clearly no such variable exists in `tests`; who'd create variables with such silly names!? There is no need to use `data$var` format in a formula, because the whole point of the `data` argument is to indicate where R should lookup the names of variables mentioned in the formula.

To start fixing this, fit your model as:

```
regression <- lm(students ~ subjects, data = train)
```

then predict using

```
predict(regression, test)
```

where `test` will need to have a column containing `subjects`.

The error message is because `newdata` has 3456 but when it search for variable `train$subjects` it found 7689 rows, presumably that is the number of complete observations in `train`...?